# How can I find out if audio books contain sex or violence before I listen to them near my child?

Tags: parents, entertainment

We listen to audio books in the car when we are on a long (>1 hour) road trip. My daughter, who is 2, watches children's TV on an iPad in the back seat during these trips and is perfectly happy to do so - it's a nice treat for her since she's not allowed TV at home.

But, a lot of audio books that are top picks have sexual or violent scenes.  For example, on our last trip there were some particularly graphic parts in the literature we were listening to - Elena Ferrante's 'Story of a New Name' (not that it is thought of as a hard-core book, in fact, it's critically acclaimed and a very good novel).

For now, our daughter is clueless but I can see that with her vocabulary expanding at a very quick pace, she will understand the words in our story if she chooses to listen. I prefer not to have to switch over to young adult books until she can really enjoy the story too.

How can I choose (still) good literature that avoids adult language and themes, without learning the entire plot ahead of time?

Edit: I know sites like https://www.commonsensemedia.org/ exist, but they only rate children's programming...

Comment: Stick to nerdy books like The Wheel of Time or Mistborn, and you'll never have to worry :) Sorry for a non-answer, there doesn't seem to be much information on books like that, only media. Good luck!

Comment: What makes you think Common Sense only rate's children's programming?  They have ratings for some pretty adult stuff like, say, [Midnight Cowboy](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/movie-reviews/midnight-cowboy) or [Game of Thrones](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/book-reviews/a-game-of-thrones-a-song-of-fire-and-ice-series) which aren't really Children oriented

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at amazon.com for the audiobooks you have and checking the categories they are under

- adult
- children
- teens

and then checking out any reviews, as coarse vocabulary is usually mentioned here if it was a surprise.